# Ramanujan and his influence on others

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, ramanujan

A few years ago I saw a paper where a few important researchers were asked which theorem of Ramanujan impressed them most.
I don't remember details, but I would like to see this paper again.
Details, please!

Comment: I don't know how can anyone answer this question :O

Answer (score 6):

I believe the request of the OP matches closely with the article [Your Hit Parade: The Top Ten Most Fascinating Formulas in Ramanujan's Lost Notebook](http://www.ams.org/journals/notices/200801/tx080100018p.pdf) by George Andrews and Bruce Berndt in the January 2008 Notices of the AMS, which involved taking a survey of 34 "renowned experts" to appropriately rank the formulas.

Comment: Thanks, Jerry, that is the article.
Wake Forest is the alma mater of Naiomi Cameron?